# button.js in ternary operator code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was just looking up the code in button.js and I saw this ternary operator that's hard to decode. Basically I am talking about the below line of code:

```
$el[val](data[state] == null ? this.options[state] : data[state])
```

I understand the below part:

```
data[state] == null ? this.options[state] : data[state]
```

But what is this:

```
$el[val]
```

I am having a problem understanding this javascript syntax, can somebody decode the complexity and explain this to me please. I ran through the code a few times, but still couldn't quite understand.

You can check out the plugin on GitHub too, here's the link : [link (line 40)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [line 31](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L31), you can see this line

```
var val  = $el.is('input') ? 'val' : 'html'
```

`val` and `html` functions of jQuery object. So, `$el[val]` returns a function reference of either `val` or `html`, which is called by passing the result of

```
data[state] == null ? this.options[state] : data[state]
```

To be more clear,

```
var func = $el[val]; // function reference is gotten
func(data[state] == null ? this.options[state] : data[state]); // invocation
```

The above is just to show how it works. In real time it would break, as context of `$el` is missing.

Comment: so ur saying basically , func(data[state] == null ? this.options[state] : data[state]); ends up being something like val(execute something) or html(execute something) .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik exactly.

Comment: Random downvoter, care to explain the downvote? @AlexanderSolonik glad to have helped you :)